# Problem with deleting of info from table

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error msg when I am trying to delete a group:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`asset_base`.`catgroup`, CONSTRAINT `catgroup_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`gid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I am not quite sure what to do. I am thinking that this would enable the deletion of group, but I am not quite sure, so I figured that someone here might know. I am trying to delete info from the groups table and it is linked to catgroup table. So if I add ON DELETE CASCADE restriction to catgroup i should be ok, right?

If I am on the right track I still would like to know how can I add a ON DELETE CASCADE option to a allready made table, hopefully without having to delete any cells or having to recreate the whole table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be fixed when you (indeed) add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` to your foreign key.

You do not have to recreate the table. Just drop the constraint `catgroup_ibfk_2` and re-create it. This time with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

Good luck!